# working with three winforms as mdi parent and child

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parent-child, mdi

I have 3 forms-Form1,2,3. Form1 is MdiContainer. Now, when a button on Form1 is clicked it shows Form2, and on Form2 when a button is clicked then it shows Form3. my code is as below but it gives error that Form2 is not MdiContainer. but if i make Form2 as MdiContainer then it gives error that Form2 is a MdiChild and can't be MdiContainer.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        f2.MdiParent = this;
    }
}
```

`public partial class Form2 : Form`

```
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
        f3.MdiParent = this;
    }
}
```

how to do this?

In short , i want that :
Parent of Form2 is Form1, and,
Parent of Form3 is Form2

Comment: It's not supported.
http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nested+mdi

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can only have one MDI parent. Within that parent container you can have many child forms, but those forms can only spawn other forms directly and not as MDI children.

In Microsoft's own words:

> The Microsoft Windows implementation of the multiple document interface (MDI) does not support nested MDI client windows. In other words, neither an MDI client window nor an MDI child window can have an MDI client window as a child.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because Form2 is not an MDI container.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this functionality is not supported, however you may be able to replicate it in other ways. Is it simply for visual representation that you want f2 to be the parent of f3? I am trying to understand in order to give you a proper answer. So what do you want to accomplish? If you want f3 to be embeded on f2, you can create a user control and add it as a control to your form.

If you want f3 to popup you could use

```
f3.showdialog();
```

If you do this don't specify the mdiparent of f3.

Eric

Comment: actually am developing a software, so i have to do this. is there any other way to accomplish this task, i mean without MDI, how are softwares built using winforms?

Comment: also, if i use ShowDialog(), then Form1 also gets disabled when Form3 is displayed. i want that Form1 is always enabled, independent of any no. of further forms i open.

Comment: You can use 'f3.show();' without 'f3.mdiparent = this;' In contrast you can set the 'f3.mdiparent = f1;' Why do you want f2 to be parent of f3?

Comment: @sqlchild: Based on what you have stated, I would probably go with Dorababu's approach and make the mdiparent of f3 = f1;

Answer (score 1):

I tried by writing as follows with out

```
 f2.MdiParent = this;
```

The code works

If you want to do with out showdialog means write the following on Button_click

```
bool IsOpen = false;
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (f.Text == "Form2") //  Name of the Form
    {
        IsOpen = true;
        f.Focus();
        break;
    }
}
if (IsOpen == false)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
   //f2.MdiParent = this;
    f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: with out Form.showdialog() we can stop the forms getting loaded for multiple times

Answer (score 0):

There is only one MdiContainer in an application and others should be child forms.

However you can approximately achieve your functionality by doing `ShowDialog` instead of `Show()`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f3.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Edit 1** Due to your comments, Solution provided by [@Dorababu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388388/dorababu) is best for you with some improvements; made `form1` as parent of `form3`. So your form3 will be displayd inside `MdiParent`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
   //f3.MdiParent = this;
    // instead use this.MdiParent
    f3.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    f2.Show();
}
```

And check on get `focus` event of form2 if `form3` is displayed then set focus to `form3`, so form2 will not get focused until form3 is opened.

```
private void Form2_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // inside Focus event of Form2
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f.Text == "Form3") //  Name of the Form
        {
            f.Focus();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do this, then Form1 also gets disabled when Form3 is displayed. i want that Form1 is always enabled, independent of any no. of further forms i open.

Comment: @sqlchild, @Dorababu 's solution is best with some modifications.